# Wave nature of light can't explain variation of heat capacity?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation

I found this line in the textbook: Wave nature of light cannot explain the variation of heat capacity of solids as a function of temperature. What does this mean and why can't it be explained?

If the question I posted has inadequate information please comment and I will edit it.

Comment: What textbook? What page? Why does it think light has anything to do with the heat capacity of solids (maybe its making an analogy between photons and phonons, the latter of which are the main (but not only) contribution to the specific heat of solids?)

Comment: @jacob1729: maybe something along these lines: it would be impossible to quantize the solid state lattice as a low energy limit of electrodynamics, without also quantizing electrodynamics itself. So since heat capacity requires phonon quantization, it also requires photon quantization. But hard to say without a specific reference by the OP.